# indexedDB with CDWKWebViewEngine in PhoneGap Build cli-6.0.0

Tags: javascript, ios, phonegap-build, indexeddb

I'm having trouble opening an indexedDB store when using CDWKWebViewEngine within an app build with PhoneGap Build 6 running on iOS 9.2. window.indexedDB is not null and appears to be of type IDBFactory but when I use the code below I get "InvalidAccessError" reported.

```
var request = window.indexedDB.open("MyTestDatabase", 1);
request.onerror = function (event) {
    alert("Database error: " + request.error.name);                
};
```

Has anyone been able to get indexedDB working in the environment I've described?

Comment: FWIW: I have it working with `cli-5.2.0` and my test device is running iOS `8.4.1` [cordova-storage-indexddb](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/cordova-storage-indexddb). Sorry I don't have notes on this. I was testing the other three forms storage at the time (file, localStorage, and sqlite).